# Getting I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed

Tags: java, android, android-service

I'm starting a service => background service, And starting a check for files in "new Thread", In the log i'm getting the following, the service/app gets paused .

Log : `I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 25935(1686KB) AllocSpace objects, 13(903KB) LOS objects, 39% free, 13MB/22MB, paused 649us total 43.569ms`

It's just a scan for files in MyData in SDcard, which contain a bunch of pics ( about 20 pics ) .

**Scan = Getting the pics names and saving them to String .

Answer (score 37, accepted):

All this means is that the garbage collector is doing its job and freeing up memory.

If you are seeing this frequently (or consistently), then you are likely allocating too many objects. A common cause is allocating many (or a few large) objects within a loop like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.create(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
}
```

Every time we hit this loop, we allocate one hundred new Bitmap objects.

The best way to prevent GC sweeps is to not allocate objects. Of course you have to allocate objects in Java, so you need to ensure that you are not allocating unnecessarily.

[Here is one of many YouTube videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OrLEoIsMIAc) that Google has release with tips on avoiding GC events and managing memory properly.

Comment: I'm having this problem with an app that worked 30 times in a row and nothing is changed in the code I just get a grey screen and it keeps doing this for an eternity. Android studio is ´crap

Comment: Android Studio is an IDE, it has nothing to do with the code running on your device. It sounds like you have a loop that is running infinitely.

Comment: The code works fine when I create a new emulator then starts doing if after a while, there are no loops in the code currently. It's a basic note app which uses sqllite, there's like 3 notes in the database atm. It seems to happen when I try to iterate over a cursor for some reason.

Comment: You should post a new question the code you believe is causing problems

Comment: I will if I can't solve it myself I'm just a little tired of android studio causing all kinds of weird issues at random times seemingly without reason. Sorry for spamming this thread.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the problem? I get this all the time now. My app will work absolutely fine, but then it will start lagging. I then go back and check my code, only to have this problem subside later. It's driving me nuts. It will go from a 2 second loading time to well over a minute. And that's from loading 20 objects

Answer (score 0):

As Bryan Herbst said: "If you are seeing this frequently" it means you have a problem.
The issue may arise from a lapsed listener, aka memory leaks.

Now.. I am not so sure how would it be a memory leak if something is being garbage collected repeatedly!?

So my reasoning is... (I am not so sure)
That the actual joint of subscription itself cannot be garbage collected, but whatever happens with the lambda/listener-output AFTER it crosses the edge of the subscription joint/barrier (between Consumer and Producer) may actually be eligible for Garbage Collection, but because the subscription is still connected, the output recontextualizes repeatedly.

On the other hand, because of how graphics work, it may be that the actual loop behind the graphical "engine" is sending information repeatedly and because nothing is being done with this data it is being garbage collected after the lapsed subscriptor receives the stream.