# Crash Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin Forms framework for android and iOS mobile platform, on iOS devices it work's well but in Android when going on a specific page app shut down.

I got this error : Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 7041(512KB) AllocSpace objects

Using breakpoint I noticed crash arrived executing this

```
var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                            newStorageUsers,
                            Formatting.None,
                            new JsonSerializerSettings()
                            {
                                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                            });
```

I show you entire demo code

**Page in which I got error**

```
private readonly IStorageUserService _storageService
public MyPage(User user)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   ...
   _storageService = new StorageUserServiceImpl();
   _storageService.StoreUser(user);
   ...
}
```

**Service Interface**

```
public interface IStorageUserService
{
    void StoreUser(User user);
}
```

**Service Implementation**

```
public class StorageUserServiceImpl : IStorageUserService
{
    private string _usersPathFile = Path.Combine(App.GetPackagePath(), "users.txt");
    public StorageUserServiceImpl()
    {
        if (!File.Exists(_usersPathFile))
        {
            _createUsersFile();
        }
    }

    private void _createUsersFile()
    {
        var file = File.Create(_usersPathFile);
        file.Close();
    }

    public void StoreUser(User user)
    {
        var currentStorage = GetStorageUsers();
        List<StorageUser> newStorageUsers = new List<StorageUser>() { };
        if (currentStorage != "" && currentStorage != "[]")
        {
            newStorageUsers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<StorageUser>>(currentStorage);
        }
        var storageUser = new StorageUser()
        {
            Infos = user,
            CreationDate = Helper.DateFormatter.NowDateTime()
            ...
        };
        newStorageUsers.Add(storageUser);

        var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                            newStorageUsers,
                            Formatting.None,
                            new JsonSerializerSettings()
                            {
                                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                            });

        _store(newStorageUsers, content);
    }
    
    private void _store(List<StorageUser> newStorageUser, string content)
    {
        // breakpoint can't be triggered there because app shut down with logs
        File.WriteAllText(_usersPathFile, content);
    }
 }
```

This service is used on several pages but I got this bug in only one page

After this message on logs :

> Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 7041(512KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(264KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 4343KB/8687KB, paused 187us total 28.412ms

I got

> Pending exception java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8192KB ...

> JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI IsInstanceOf called with pending exception java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8192KB ...

> Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 8815 (om.myapp.app), pid 8815

I've no more details of what happened, how can I fix this please?

Comment: how large is the object you're serializing?  What happens if you change the value of `ReferenceLoopHandling`?

Comment: Thank's for your help, my object can be large with 30 keys or more, if I remove `ReferenceLoopHandling` I've an another error. If I comment serialization I've no error but I need to serialize it

Comment: According to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35341435/getting-i-art-explicit-concurrent-mark-sweep-gc-freed), you may need to do something to avoid GC event.

Comment: yes I agree, but I don't understand what occurs this, I just want to serialize an object , maybe is too long ?

Comment: The only solution I found it's to remove this service from my view and call it in other page, if you have more information to help

Comment: If the cause is too long, you can add the android:largeHeap="true" into the application label of the AndroidManifest.xml to request more memory.

Comment: Thank you I will try it